# Huawei P40 Google Play Services dialog

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, huawei-mobile-services

I want to run my app on `Huawei P40`. This phone is not supporting Google Play Services. So I made APK for `AppGallery.` App is working fine (only Google Maps cant be opened) but as I change some tabs or content, some system dialog will popup with message `"MyApp won't run without Google Play services, which are not supported by your device."` This dialog can be closed on tap but it will reappear everytime I switch `Activity` or `Fragment`.

Is there any way how to disable this message? I implemented `HMS` to my `Gradle` files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That pop-up usually occurs due to having following methods in code

```
GoogleApiAvailability.makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable
GoogleApiAvailability.showErrorDialogFragment
GoogleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog
```

In order to overcome this, having a control like below should be helpful and works on my case

```html
GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();

int errorCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

googleApiAvailability.makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
googleApiAvailability.showErrorNotification(this, errorCode);
googleApiAvailability.showErrorDialogFragment(this, errorCode, 100);

Dialog errorDialog = googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, errorCode, 100);
errorDialog.show();
errorDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Play pop-up has been dismissed!");
    }
});
```

Alternatively, it is also possible to utilize isGooglePlayServicesAvailable method and handle its return states SUCCESS, SERVICE_MISSING, SERVICE_UPDATING, SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, SERVICE_DISABLED, SERVICE_INVALID

Comment: Also the call to `LocationServices` causes the warning dialog. For example,  `LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity)`